# Is it possible to create two different submit button in one form in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

So I'm working on my Django project and ran into an issue. I have a custom ModelForm, with which I'm trying two different works. I'm trying to create two submit buttons for the form, one for normal submission, and the other for making changes to the input data and then submitting. 
For Example, let's say I have `name` field in my form. If the user clicks button A, `name` is submitted. But if the user clicks button B, I want the `name` field to be submitted as `name@gmail.com`. 
Is it possible to have two buttons working differently in one Django form? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, in your view you would do something like this:

```
class SomeView(UpdateView):
    
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        if 'add-email' in self.request.POST:
            self.object.name = f'{self.object.name}@gmail.com'
            
        self.object.save()
```

Then in your template:

```
<form ...>
    <button type="submit" name="save">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="add-email">Submit with Email</button>
</form>
```